# LC-3 Assembly Language - Printing out just specific parts of input

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have to write a program that asks for input for cards from a deck and then prints out only the face cards so if I were to type in 5JKQ894 it would echo just JKQ but I can't figure out how to just print the face cards.

Comment: You say you can't figure out how to just print the face cards but do you have an idea about how to ask for user input? Would you input a single string or repeat inputting separate characters? Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: I would input a single string and then press enter which is the newline and then it should print out the face cards that were in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way to solve it:

First establish the length of your string. This would depend on the function you used to input.
Next initialize a pointer at the start of the string and one after the other compare each character in it with the lower bound "A" and the upper bound "Z". If it's a match then print the original character.
Repeat comparing/outputing until the length is exhausted.

ps: Probably best to additionally compare with lower bound "a" and upper bound "z"